# Adding traductions files in pygtk

Tags: python, translation, pygtk, glade

I'm working on an movielist interface using python, gtk+3 and glade and I want it to be in two languages. I've followed the instructions I've found on different sites, but I have a problem. I have the po file with the translation (english to spanish) but now, when it comes to adding that file with the translation to the code I run in all sort of errors.

```
    gtk.glade.textdomain(APP)
    gtk.glade.bindtextdomain(APP, DIR)
```

Being APP the file name and DIR the directory, but the gtk name doesn't exist and I can't import it without running into a segmentation fault error.

So, I basically need to know how to add the translation files in my pygtk code. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most popular way to Internationalize (I18N) an application is to use gettext.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html

Wrap the strings to translate like this _(u"This text is to be translated")

A nice tool to translate strings is poEdit http://poedit.net/

Comment: Okay, this works for translating the strings in the python code...
But for the text in glade, that won't work...

Comment: Never used glade, but it seems it stores the def's in an xml file and marks strings to translate with 'translatable="yes"', so you need to teach poedit to handle that additional keyword.  Maybe this page will help: http://www.servin.com/linux/GladeInternationalization.html